# In IOS App, page's layout changes from UIRectEdgeNone to UIRectEdgeAll during page jump

Tags: ios

In my IOS App, I have a page A whose layout is `UIRectEdgeNone` and a page B whose layout is `UIRectEdgeAll`. When I jump from A to B, in page B:
1. Because the initial layout is `UIRectEdgeNone`, so page B will layout below the system navigationbar
2. Then the layout is `UIRectEdgeAll`, so page B will layout at the beginning of the screen
3. So,I will see the move of page B's UI from (0,44) to (0,0)

How to solve the problem?